# Conditional disables needed class on <li> tag

Tags: conditionals

When I use this conditional it works great, it activates the active state when I am in segment 1, however, at the same time it disables the other class on the li 'dropdown'.

The 'dropdown' class is  positioning relative, when its disabled  the dropdown menu moves all the way to the right of the parent container.

Is their a different conditional which will allow me to NOT DISABLE the 2nd class (dropdown)  on the il tag.

{if segment_1 == "donate"} class="active"{/if} class="dropdown">Donate

Answer (score 5):

Well, you're having an HTML issue, not an EECMS issue, because an element can't have more than one`class` attribute.

Use this:

```
<li class="{if segment_1 == "donate"}active {/if}dropdown">Donate</li>
```

Or you can simple remove the `dropdown` class and use a [child selector or a descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html). Even for JavaScript, you don't need this class. You can do an Event delegation at its parentElement.